# Answer with appropriate "link only" (almost) answer or comment and vote-to-close?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, link-only-answers

I'm referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29766329/2173917) question <sup>(10k users only; no Wayback Machine capture)</sup>.

In this scenario, the *answer* will be a very short one containing the link, that's acceptable and the right thing. There is nothing much to *explain* separately, as such or (IMHO) not required, either.

Shall we

- put that "link" as an answer?
- leave a comment  (requestion to perform a basic search first, with a hint to the answer, possibly with required link)?
- downvote (if warrants, for reason like "no research effort")?
- vote to close?

I'm asking this because, if the **answer** is posted, OP might be *encouraged* to post similar questions in future. What is the suggested course of action in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answerer got it right, but posted what IMHO is a low quality answer. You can easily open that link and look at the information provided about the topic, and see that the answer given is not really a complete one, and it lacks of fundamental content. The OP asked for the meaning of the `bdata` private word in variable's declarations, so a clear and complete answer should explain:

- What's its meaning;
- Where it can be used;
- Why and when you should use it.

**This is, rather than a "link only answer", an answer showing minimal effort**. Even the link is simply copied and pasted into the answer (and IMHO that's pretty ugly to see): when posting a link it's always better to write something like `You can find additional information [here](link)` than just pasting the link without an explanation.

In this particular case, a flag is a bit exaggerated, and it would probably be declined: the best thing to do is to **comment the answer or downvoting it, explaining to the user that he should improve it with more information and explanation**. Do not be afraid to lose that precious point of reputation downvoting! Downvotes are here for a reason, and you'll always get the chance of removing it or converting it into an upvote if the user edits the answer. An edit to the post would also be an option, but a *radical* edit isn't always the right thing, and you should teach the user to do it by their own.

Since that the question itself lacks of effort by the OP, a comment explaining why it should be better to improve it would be also helpful for the OP.

---

### But...

> ... I don't know much about that platform.

You don't need to have any kind of skill in C or any other language to notice that the post is not well explained/researched. You only need a little programming background, and the only concept of "variable" and "private word" will help you deduce that, when explaining the purpose of a private word, you should provide more information (see the above points).

> ... the answer is from a high-rep user!

**High-rep users are not saints**. Yes, they tend to post better content than low-rep users, but this doesn't mean that they couldn't be capable of posting crappy answers. It happens, and sometimes the reason is right in the high reputation: they are more experienced, and may tend to omit fundamental things taking them for granted.

> ... my comment only got 2 upvotes while the question had 28 views by that time.

Two upvotes only mean that two other people are of your own opinion, and supporting you on your choice. When voting to close, 3 close votes are not so useless.

Comment: Point 1)  I'm not knowledable in that platform. Point 2) the answer is from a high-rep user Point 3) My comment only got 2 upvotes while the question has 28 views till time. So, i'm a bit confused about my understanding. Probably i'll wait a bit more here for others to add their views, too. No offence, please. :-) and thanks for sharing your  view.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I added a bit more explaination, hope it helps

Comment: :-) I never said `so I'm not sure about what to do.` I already did my part, if you see. I was trying to get my action verified and (possibly) collect a tip for best practice in these kind of scenario.

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry I misunderstood that little part, edited :)

Comment: make it at least "at <url>", that's slightly better than "here".